# Extend movement of input range with large custom thumb image

Tags: html, css

I am making a custom input range using a 40px x 80px image as the thumb background. Normally the thumb only moves within the length of the track from edge to edge. I want the thumb to overlap the edges of the track so the middle of the image touches both ends of the track.

Comment: Can you post a complete verifiable example e.g. via jsfiddle? it's hard to diagnose what you mean without more of an example. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527475/own-image-as-slider-thumb-on-range-how-to-style-on-css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zLg03h8s/

Comment: Notice that the top of the thumb won't go past the top edge and the bottom won't go past the bottom like a real slider would.

Comment: Try like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sc5d2eba/ the problem (i think) is the transform which is throwing the height off. At least in that example for webkit it does what you want I think

Comment: My goal is to have 40x80 pixel thumb and I want a 40px overlap at either end of the slider similar to a mixer. I've made another fiddle with thumb offset and removed all the tranforms for clarity. Notice the thumb won't move beyond either end of the track. https://jsfiddle.net/vkscypah/

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly 40 pixels but it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/owhdr658/2/

Comment: Jay, I don't think you're are understanding my goal. It isn't the size of the thumb I'm interested in. I want the thumb to travel beyond the ends of the track up to the middle of the thumb.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience,  if you can show with pictures or an example of what exactly your trying to achieve I will try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a simple answer for this. Turn off input range decorations and place in a div and decorate the div to look like a track, center, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to do this, and I am not entirely sure what you have done for your solution, but, I think I have an answer.

Style your thumb with a small width/height and then apply a scale transform to it.

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: scaleX(100) scaleY(100);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: scaleX(100) scaleY(100);
}    

input[type="range"]::::-ms-thumb {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(10) scaleY(10);
}
```

Because the transform happens after the layout, the input responds as though you are moving the tiny thumb but the displayed thumb (and 'clickable' area) are much larger.

You can play with the width, height and scaleX and scaleY values until you get the behaviour and styling you desire.

The only thing that may or may not be desirable from a user experience point of view is that if you click towards the edge of the thumb, it will snap the centre to that location.

Hope it Helps